# How do I center navbar items in bootstrap (mx-auto doesn't work)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            About
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            products
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            gallery
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            order
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            contact
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I can't center the nav-items. It would align to the right even when I put mx-auto. I tried margin-left but then it wouldn't be responsive. It would only center navbar-nav but not the item inside of them. How would I fix this? Thank you

Comment: There is no error in the code structure, which version of the bootstrap version is it?

Comment: I used your code and the navbar is center. please share more your code

Comment: Oh sorry I have .nav-item { margin: 30px 10%; } in css so it would look like its right-aligned when they have margin

Answer (score 0):

You can these classes,

`text-center` or `container-fluid` or use flex box `flex justify-center`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "display: flex" and "justify-content: center" which might help you to solve this issue. If you want to align the text, you can use "text-align: center".